# filter and copy data from one spreadsheet to another while criteria is in different spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, xcode, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two google sheets forst one is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJtjlkxCDFOIhJxpMJl4PcpJKL4nvGVtk2LDgVhbuNQ/edit#gid=0
and the second is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGw6dHpYE4ABvsE8S6dIPe7kLQ1eZW95Xp2F1oPHX5c/edit#gid=0

I want to filer data in first sheet base on the criteria which presents in the second sheet "Automate!D3" and then copy the filtered data to second sheet in "Filtered_Data". and want to this process automate so in future when i add more data to sheet one so that can be copy to below data in sheet two.

i can not able to filter throw app script, so i want to help in this.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
const dsid = "1PJtjlkxCDFOIhJxpMJl4PcpJKL4nvGVtk2LDgVhbuNQ";
const tssid = "1ZGw6dHpYE4ABvsE8S6dIPe7kLQ1eZW95Xp2F1oPHX5c"

function filterByDate() {
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dsid).getSheetByName('DT').getDataRange().getValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tssid);
  const criteria = tss.getSheetByName('Automate').getRange('D3').getValue();
  const ts = tss.getSheetByName('Filtered_Data');
  const results = values
    .filter(row => row[1].getDate == criteria.getDate)
    .map(row => [row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]]);
  
  ts.getRange(2,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

I would suggest to place the criteria value in the daily sheet, and install the function into daily sheet as an edit trigger.

Make sure that the 'criteria' and the 'date' column are both formatted as 'Date' format.

The follow code has changed the way to get values.
Insead of .getValues(), it now uses .getDisplayValues(), and convert the string back into date obj afterwards.

```js
const dsid = "1PJtjlkxCDFOIhJxpMJl4PcpJKL4nvGVtk2LDgVhbuNQ";
const tssid = "1ZGw6dHpYE4ABvsE8S6dIPe7kLQ1eZW95Xp2F1oPHX5c";

function filterByDate() {
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dsid).getSheetByName('DT').getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tssid);
  const criteria = tss.getSheetByName('Automate').getRange('D3').getDisplayValues();
  const ts = tss.getSheetByName('Filtered_Data');
  const results = values
    .filter(row => new Date(row[1]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == new Date(criteria).setHours(0,0,0,0))
    .map(row => [row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]]);
  
  ts.getRange(2,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: it's not working bro, it fetches all the data without filtering and also can not put criteria in the same spreadsheet it has to be there. I would appreciate it if you could help as per the conditions.

Comment: if it does not filter the data, that means either the date column in Daily sheet, or the Criteria value in the Target sheet (or both) are not formated as date format. Working with datevalues in javascript can somethings be tricky.

Comment: Maybe try console.log() the date column and criteria value to see if they are shown as date object with the correct date and time in the console?

Comment: both dates are formatted but still, it is not working and did not get the console.log thing as I am new to coding.

Comment: would you consider read a little bit of documation from any of the javascript resource? console.log() is the very basic way to debug. You MUST know it to be able to do any kind of coding.

Comment: I just noticed that you didn't mention which column do you want to filter, I was assuming that you are filtering the 'Date' column, and you said that the script fetches all the data without filtering... But in your sample data, all data have the same date in the 'Date' column...

Comment: i changed the data before trying your code bro, then only I said it it is not working. now it has different dates but still it is not working.

Comment: which part is not working? Did you get any error in console? Did you tried the 2nd method I’ve provided?

Comment: second code worked. thanks for the help buddy.